# How to handle the error "first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Please can anyone tell me why I am getting this error in Mongoose. I am new to it , please help me in this code...

> Error : The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

My db.js code is

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const connectDb = async()=>{
    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
            useUnifiedTopology:true,
            useNewUrlParser:true,
            useCreateIndex:true
        })
        console.log(`Mongo connect ${conn.connection.host}`)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(`Error : ${error.message}`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
export default connectDb;
```

And my MONGO_URL is in .env

And my server.js code is

```
import express  from 'express'
import dotnev  from 'dotenv'
import connectDb from './config/db.js'

connectDb()
const app = express()
dotnev.config()


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('API is running...')
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT,console.log('Server running at 5000 port'))
```

my Terminal is showing

> Error : The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to DB *before* you set up environment variables, that's why `MONGO_URL = undefined` during connecting. Call `dotnev.config()` first:

```js
dotnev.config() // set .env variables
connectDb()     // connect w/ access to them
```